# Powershell export result to txt with format

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that looks for the two files with the smallest size and exports them to a txt.
The problem is that the result is exported with a "bit weird format".

```
$checksize = gci -r| sort -descending -property length | select -last 2 name, length | Add-Content -Path C:\log.txt
```

And the result

```
@{Name=fileexample.txt; Length=3482342}
@{Name=server.iso; Length=548238474}
```

I would like only the names of the files and their size to appear.Does anyone know how I could do it?

Thanks.
Good Day

Comment: Please show us the desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
#sample path to csv file
$CsvFile = Import-CSV -Path C:\data.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header File,Length

ForEach ($u in $CsvFile)
{
$A = ($u.File).Replace("@{Name=","")
$B = (($u.Length).Replace("Length=","")).Replace("}","")
Write-Host $A $B
}
```

or export to csv

```
gci -Path C:\test -r| sort -descending -property length | select -last
2 name, length|Export-Csv C:\log.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Out-File** instead of **Add-Content**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).